# how to move contacts from phone to Google account

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have contacts stored locally on my phone and also I have contacts on Google.. But in kitkat I'm not able to sync these internal with google account like on android ICS

Comment: What do you mean 'I'm not able to sync'? Have you tried `Settings > Accounts > Google` and selecting your Gmail account to sync the contacts?

Answer (score 1):

If you export the local contact of your phone to a file then you can import that file on google contacts: www.google.com/contacts